# Compare int and Object in Java

Tags: java, object

I have the following code:

```
Object obj = 3;
//obj.equals(3); // so is this true?
```

Does `obj` equal to 3?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: `obj.equals(3)` was true, but I'd like to know if it was only "luck" or it really equals to 3

Comment: You're thinking along the right lines.  Depending on luck sucks.

Comment: For a variation try `3` and `3L`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's at play here is autoboxing.

When you use a primitive literal when a reference is expected, the primitive is [autoboxed](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) to the wrapper type (in this case from int to Integer).

Your code is the equivalent of this:

```
Object obj = Integer.valueOf(3);
if ( obj.equals(Integer.valueOf(3)) ) {
    //...
```

I'll leave it to you to decide whether that's true or not.

Answer (score 4):

This is also interesting:

```
Object t = 3;

t.equals( 3 );  // true
3 == t;         // true
```

But

```
Object h = 128; 

h.equals( 128 ); // true 
128 == h;        // false
```

`.equals`  will work, becase the value will be compared. `==` Will work, using the references,  but only from -128 to 127, because the autoboxing mechanism, uses an internal pool to hold "most commonly used" references.

Strange enough:  `o == 3`  will fail at compile time.

Comment: o?  Where is that declared?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Here is what's happening behind the scenes.

```
Object obj = Integer.valueOf(3);
obj.equals(Integer.valueOf(3));
```

So, of course they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement will set obj to be a automatically boxed Integer (the same as Integer.valueOf(3))

Hence the second statement will return true.

Answer (score 0):

#### You need to do  Type-casting here to achieve the task

```
         Object obj = 3;
         if(obj.equals(Integer.valueOf(3)))
         {
        // to do something....  
         }
```